# Stored property overriding in Swift - private vs non-private

Tags: swift, inheritance

```
class A {

}

class R {
    let foo: A

    init(foo: A) {
        self.foo = foo
    }

    func printIt() {
        print(self.foo)
    }
}


class AA: A {

}

class RR: R {
    let foo: AA

    init(foo: AA) {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init(foo: foo)
    }
}
```

If I try to write the above code, Swift compiler is giving me an error `Cannot override with a stored property 'foo'`, but if I make foo `private`

```
class A {

}

class R {
    private let foo: A

    init(foo: A) {
        self.foo = foo
    }

    func printIt() {
        print(self.foo)
    }
}


class AA: A {

}

class RR: R {
    private let foo: AA

    init(foo: AA) {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init(foo: foo)
    }
}
```

Swift compiler does not throw an error and compiles perfectly without any error. Also I am not required to use keyword `override` here and if I do, Swift compiler throws and error saying `Property does not override any property from its superclass`.

Could someone explain in details how the inheritance and overriding works in Swift and is it something special incase of private properties?

Comment: Actually making `foo` from `R` private is enough, this way `RR` will not know about it, thus no need to `override` and no conflict.

Comment: A `private` property is private to that class and not available outside of that class implementation (including not available to subclasses). So subclass doesn’t `override` it since it never inherited it in the first place. There isn’t much more to it than that. For a discussion of inheritance in general, see [The Swift Programming Language: Inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html), though it admittedly doesn’t go into this particular detail.

Comment: Got it, thank you!